# Draw on Video Xamarin

Tags: c#, video, xamarin, mobile

Using Xamarin, I am trying to implement the feature that allows a user to draw on top of a video. Note that the drawing doesn't need to be saved.

I would like some input on what the best way of implementing this. My initial though would be to create a drawable custom view that when the user clicks the draw icon, the current frame of the video is passed to that drawable view.

This seems like a pretty great plugin, which I could use to create a custom view https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager.

Would really appreciate any help or suggestions :)